# JavaFX MVC inter package comunication

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, javafx-8, observer-pattern

My team and I are creating a university project. We have to create an application that emulates the famouse game Monopoly in Java. We are using JavaFX as graphic library.
This is my first "big" project and now that we have got all the MVC parts completed, we need to make them communicate.

My view must update every time a player pays money or if its pawn moves on the board and in a lot of other cases. 
We have a GameEngine controller that relates all the Controller/Model components.

My question (that plagues me from several days) is:
*If I create a ViewController that gets the data from the GameEngine and then this controller updates the view, is that a MVC violation ?*

Or is better to create many methods in my ViewController that updates single components that could be called by other controllers? In this case, which would be the best way to do it?

**This is a part of my ViewController**

```
public class ViewController {
        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance0;

        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance1;

        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance2;

        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance3;

        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance4;

        @FXML
        private Label playerBalance5;

        private List<Label> playerBalances = new ArrayList<Label>(Arrays.asList(playerBalance0, playerBalance1, 
playerBalance2, playerBalance3, playerBalance4, playerBalance5));

        public void updatePlayerBalances(final Map<Integer, Double> balances) {
           balances.forEach((K, V) -> {
              if (V.equals(0.0)) {
                 this.playerBalances.get(K).setText("");
              } else {
                 this.playerBalances.get(K).setText(String.format("%.0f",  V));
              }
           });
        }

}
```

Is it correct that other classes give me the data to display like in this code snippet? Or would be better something like this:

```
public class ViewController {
            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance0;

            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance1;

            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance2;

            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance3;

            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance4;

            @FXML
            private Label playerBalance5;

            private List<Label> playerBalances = new ArrayList<Label>(Arrays.asList(playerBalance0, playerBalance1, 
    playerBalance2, playerBalance3, playerBalance4, playerBalance5));

            public void updatePlayerBalances() {
                Map<Integer, Double> balancs = GameEngine.getBalances();
                balances.forEach((K, V) -> {
                  if (V.equals(0.0)) {
                     this.playerBalances.get(K).setText("");
                  } else {
                     this.playerBalances.get(K).setText(String.format("%.0f",  V));
                  }
               });
            }

    }
```

I thank you in advance and I apologize for my English.

Comment: Not sure what the question is. Some code with a desciption of a specific issue, maybe? A ViewController controls the view, `We have a GameEngine controller that relates all the Controller/Model components.` Isn't that already your inter package communication transport?

Comment: My doubt is if my controller associated to the FXML file can go into my model classes and get all the data he needs or if i need tha some other controllers give me these data.

Now I'm gonna attach some code at the main question.

Comment: Who is the caller of your method updatePlayerBalances? If it is your game engine, just pass the balances as a parameter of the updatePlayerBalances as you do in the first code snippet. If it is something else calling updatePlayerBalances and needs to be decoupled from the Game engine, than your second example is fine

Comment: Thank you @b3tuning!